# How does one split a list in python knowing a sublist of it?

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a more efficient way (if available) to split a list into two sub-lists.
An example of the original list:

```
full_list = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 'v1', 'v2']
```

NOTE:
**In general the original list contains an arbitrary amount of elements that are mixed together.** The 't1' ... 't5' just serve to indicate elements of the first sub-list:

```
t_sub_list = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']
```

This sub-list is a given.

I would like to most efficiently generate the second sub-list:

```
v_sub_list = ['v1', 'v2']
```

The solutions that come to my mind are:

```
v_sub_list_A = [list_element for list_element in full_list if list_element not in t_sub_list]
v_sub_list_B = list(set(full_list) - set(t_sub_list))
```

The question I have is - is there any more efficient way of doing this?
Or at least any package that would allow to achieve the result in a more code-readable fashion?

Comment: `t_sub_list` is always at the beginning of  `full_list` ?  or could be in the middle?

Comment: t_sub_list is a random subset of full_list

Comment: ok, but the elements are unique?

Comment: yes. The elements in my case come from a listing of a directory. Hence, as filenames they are unique.

Comment: Do the elements form `t_sub_list` are a consecutive block of elements from full_list ? or just random numbers?

Comment: The elements are fully random. The only given is that the full list is not empty, nor are both the sublists.

Answer (score 7):

As stated, it's even easier than that.  Since all of the first list elements are on the left, you need only deal with finding the break point.  Use the list length.

```
full_list = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 'v1', 'v2']
t_sub_list = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']

left_size = len(t_sub_list)
v_sub_list = full_list[left_size:]
```

This yields the result you described.

Comment: as in the other answer posted - this will not solve the general case - where the list elements are randomly mixed.
I have emphasized it now in the question, since it was overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the t_sub_list with all your full_list so it will split the v_sub_list.....

```
full_list = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 'v1', 'v2']
t_sub_list= ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']
v_sub_list=[]

for i in full_list:                 
    if i in t_sub_list:
        pass
    if i not in t_sub_list:
        v_sub_list.append(i)
print(v_sub_list)
```

the output will be.....

```
['v1', 'v2']
```

Comment: this won't work in my case, since the list elements are mixed together randomly. I only emphasized the splitting into two sub-lists.
Hence slicing won't solve it.

Comment: @glamredhel-I am edited the code ....now you can check

Comment: A much shorter version that does this is already posted in the question:
t_A = [list_element for list_element in full_list if list_element not in t_sub_list]
Please read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

since `t_sub_list`  it is not always at the beginning of `full_list` and your elements are unique you can use:

```
full_list = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 'v1', 'v2']
t_sub_list = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']

start_index = full_list.index(t_sub_list[0])
t_size = len(t_sub_list)

v_sub_list = full_list[0:start_index] + full_list[start_index + t_size:]
# ['v1', 'v2']
```

you are searching the index for the first item from `t_sub_list` and then you calculate the size of `t_sub_list` in order to take all the elements around your `t_sub_list`

---

if in your `t_sub_list` are random numbers form `full_list` you can use a list comprehension:

```
t_sub_lis = set(t_sub_lis) # will make search O(1)
v_sub_list = [e for e in full_list if e not in t_sub_list]
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully.
1. The elements of the t_sub_list are not necessarily a consecutive block. They are randomly mixed with the other elements.
2. The list comprehension solution and the set difference solution I have posted in the question itself - I am asking if there are any other, more efficient / more elegant solutions than those two.

Comment: @glamredhel My last solution is more efficient since I use a set in the list comprehension